# iterm broken pipe when running tmux from profile command

Tags: linux, zsh, tmux, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

Getting **Broken Pipe** when executing `tmux` command from profile on iterm2. 
When I execute `tmux` from command line there is no problem.

```
>echo $PATH 
>/Users/myname/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin/tmux:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin
```

The path seems to be ok. 
Any idea how to fix that ?[image]

Comment: What do you get when you type `which tmux`?

Comment: Please show the relevant code and/or state the errors. Please don't use links to images. The text is missing from the question. The text on the picture is too small for some people to read. The text on the image cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors. Also see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/608639)

Answer (score 1):

The solution was adding full path to the command 
`/usr/local/bin/tmux`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: You do not have `/usr/local/bin/` in path, only `/usr/local/bin/tmux`.

`/usr/local/bin/tmux` is not a directory, it is an executable.

`$PATH` searches all its directories in the order specified for an executable that you're looking for. There is no `tmux` inside `/usr/local/bin/tmux`, so it doesn't find anything there.

You need to make your path include `/usr/local/bin`